# Where does Tumbler (of Thunar) store/cache its thumbnails?

Tags: thumbnails, file-manager, xfce, thunar

Tumbler is the thumbnailer for Thunar, from XFCE.

**Where does it store its thumbnails? Where is the thumbnail cache?**

I managed to see

`#define THUMBNAILER_CACHE_PATH    "/org/freedesktop/thumbnails/Cache1"`

in the source code for Tumbler. Not sure if it's useful. I can't find the rest of the path, nor can I find this portion on my machine.

It's not `~/.thumbnails`, and it's not `~/.cache/thumbnails`.

Answer (score 2):

Tumbler is an implementation of [Thumbnail management DBus specification](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/DraftSpecs/ThumbnailerSpec?action=show&redirect=ThumbnailerSpec), which in turn relies on [Thumbnail Managing Standard](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/thumbnail-spec/thumbnail-spec-latest.html). It stores thumbnails in `$XDG_CACHE_HOME/thumbnails/`, usually `~/.cache/thumbnails`. At that path two directories are used: `normal` and `large`, more details [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/thumbnail-spec/thumbnail-spec-latest.html#DIRECTORY).

Here on my system I have over one thousand thumbnails in either directories. Are you sure `tumblerd` is running?